# JqueryMobile - Migration from 1.3.2 to 1.4.2 - Panel transparent on Slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel, slide

i have a problem due the migration of an cordova-app (jquery + jquery mobile) from version 1.3.2 to 1.4.2.

I have provided an example here:
http://wasted-dreams.de/tmp/

as you can see, the panel navigation slides in, and on slide out it stays transparent in the background for a few ms. after that it disapears correctly.
the effect is also present on slideIN but its faster and mostly not visible.

the css class which is added on the animation is ".ui-panel-animate" and after animation should have ended the element gets an additional attribute "panel-closed"

so far my analysis. but i realy didn't find any css option or JS stuff of my code which can be responsible for that effect.

have anybody an idea how to get this fixed?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a transparent background which allows you to see through the content to the panel underneath.  You can either add a background or just change the `panel-display` attribute to `push` or `overlay` instead of the default `reveal`

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="menue" data-theme="a">
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uPqFD/)**

In the demo, you can remove the `data-display="push"` from the panel to see your issue reproduced.

API reference: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-display

**UPDATE:** the ui-panel-wrapper is definitely transparent.

Add this CSS, and the problem goes away:

```
.ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(35, 71, 160) !important;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uPqFD/1/)**

Comment: i had a look, inspecting the elements with Google, its not transparency (css) the issue, none that i could see anyway. To be honest i'm baffled, this issue is weird. something like a bug somewhere/maybe. But then i'm not a true expert, 99% of times i can hunt down issues like these. Maybe its something easy. I like to know to be honest.

Comment: @Tasos, see my updated answer. The .ui-panel-wrapper DIV which contains the non-panel content is definitely transparent (see your design-1.4.2.css file). Giving this div a background color or linear gradient, etc. eliminates the problem.

Comment: Nice one well done. I wonder were that wrapper comes from. If you inspect the elements Panel or otherwise there is no such entry. I would have thought they be a transparent entry somewhere for that. Again well done.